# Is facebook id always the same regardless if user has changed device?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm developing an Android app in which I've implemented facebook login. It works fine, I'm getting all the data from fb login for every user. I've created the new app under `facebook for developers` site: https://developers.facebook.com and added in Android app's project file `facebook_app_id` and `fb_login_protocol_scheme` values.

In the facebook login process I get `facebook_id` value for every user. My question is, will this value always be the same regardless if user has changed a device?

For instance, if user has a facebook application and he's logged in in that application and logged in in my Android app. And later he decides to install facebook app on another device with my Android app and login in to it, will user's `facebook_id` still be the same? Keep in mind that I won't change or delete application created under `facebook for developers` site.

Or another case could be, user deletes his facebook app, install it again and logs in in to it again, will `facebook_id` still be the same? Or if user is logged in in more than one device will `facebook_id` still be the same? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The user id is specific to your app (app-scoped user id.) Of course it stays the same regardless which device the user logs in from.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.